# This model works, but I do not understand how the signal works

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following in model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    ROLE = (
        ('CUSTOMER', 'User'),  # (value to be set on model, human readable value)
        ('WORKER', 'Worker'),
    )

    role = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = ROLE, default = 'USER')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I also have a corresponding form that, when filled out and sumbitted, saves to the database as a Profile properly.

What I do not understand is `instance.profile.save()` how does this work? To me it appears it should be `instance.Profile.save()` since, `Profile`exists. I am not sure where this lowercase `profile`is coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django, reverse accessors are defined with the name of the related model in **lowercase** by default.

As your `Profile` model has a `one-to-one` relationship with `User` model, you can access *profile* instance belonging to a `User` instance (say **user**) as `user.profile`.

You can override this naming with a parameter where you define the OneToOneField in your model definition with the keyword argument `related_name`.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myprofile')
```

Now, you access via `user.myprofile`

See Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)

By the way, be careful when you are accessing profile of a user via User instance. If there is no `Profile` record associated with that `User` instance, a `DoesNotExist` exception is raised.